# Making `td`s span throughout the whole row

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm having troubles spanning the `td` throughout the whole `tr` that they are inside, but i can't get it to work properly. Here is the screenshot:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZQGO.png)

There was already a question with the rows, but this time `td`s are giving problems.

```
<div className="jumbotron col-sm-12 text-left row">
                    <div className="panel panel-info">
                        <div className="panel-heading">
                            HEADER
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <table
                        id="templateTable"
                        className="table table-bordered table-condensed table-responsive">
                        <tbody className="row">
                            <tr className="col-sm-6">
                                <td className="col-sm-12">
                                    {"Hello1"}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr className="col-sm-6">
                                <td className="col-sm-12">
                                    {"Hello2"}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

Comment: Why are you using tables with bootstrap grid columns? Its not a good practice.

Comment: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/tables/

Comment: This is a css issue, not a javascript issue, please untag javascript

Comment: Are those `className` atrributes all over the place supposed to be `class`?

Comment: @TommyO, thats react. sorry i removed that tag

Comment: Please make a sample on jsfiddle or bootply or other site with all dependencies we need to try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `colspan` attribute of the `td` element that you want to span across the entire table:

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Sum: $180</td>
    <!-- notice this td spans multiple columns -->
  </tr>
</table>
```

Basically you just need to set `colspan` equal to the number of columns in your table to take the entire width of the table.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp